# Filling up an output vector with stata loop

Tags: excel, loops, foreach, stata, percentile

When you take centiles of a variable in Stata, for eg.

```
    *set directory
    cd"C:\Etc\Etc Etc\"
    *open data file
    use "dataset.dta",clear
    *get centiles
    centile var1, centile(1,5(5)95,99)
```

is there some way to record the resulting centile table to excel?  The centile values are stored in r(c_#), where # indicates the centile at which you want the data.  But I need a vector of the values at all the centiles, more or less as it appears in the output window.

I have attempted to use foreach loop to get the centiles into a vector, as follows:

```
    *Create column of centiles
    foreach i in r(centiles) {
    xx[1,`i']=r(c_`i')
    }
```

without success.

Thanks

EDIT:

I've since found this to work:

```
   matrix X = 0,0 
   forvalues i=1/21  { 
   matrix X = `i',round(r(c_`i'),.001)\ X
   }
```

Only inconveniences are 1) I have to include a a first row of 0,0 in the output, which I will then subsequently drop.  2) In this case I have 21 centiles, but it would be nice to automate the number of centiles in case I want to change it, for example something like this:

```
   forvalues i=1/r(n_cent)  { 
   matrix X = `i',round(r(c_`i'),.001)\ X
   }
```

But the "i=1/r(n_cent)" is invalid syntax.  Any advice as to how I might overcome these two inconveniences would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following syntax.

Load some data and compute the percentiles.

```
sysuse auto, clear
centile price, centile(1,5(5)95,99)
```

The matrix that is supposed to contain the results has to be initialized. This matrix is called `X`. It has as many rows as there are centiles requested via the `centile` command. It has two columns. At this stage, the matrix is populated with zeroes.

```
matrix X = J(`=wordcount("`r(centiles)'")', 2, 0)
```

The following loop is stepping through the results of the `centile` command and is replacing the zeroes in matrix `X` with the appropriate results. The first column of the matrix contains the number of the centile (1, 5, 10, ...) and the second column contains the result

```
forvalues i = 1 / `=wordcount("`r(centiles)'")' {
    local cent: word `i' of `r(centiles)'
    matrix X[`i', 1] = `cent'
    matrix X[`i', 2] = r(c_`i')
}
```

Print the results:

```
matrix list X
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `round()`, you are likely doing something wrong. There are few reasons to deliberately lose precision in the data; you can always display as many digits as you like using `format` this way or another (either applied to the data, or as an option of `list` or `matrix list`).

1. I wrote `epctile` command that returns percentiles as an estimation command, i.e., in the `e(b)` vector. This can be usable immediately; `findit epctile` to download.
2. You can modify your proposal as follows:

   ```
   local thenumlist 1, 5(5)95, 99
   centile variable, centile(`thenumlist')
   forvalues i=1/`=r(n_cent)'  { 
     matrix X = nullmat(X) \ r(c_`i')
   }
   numlist "`thenumlist'"
   matrix rownames X = `r(numlist)'
   matrix list X, format(%9.3f)
   ```